# Pandas Comparing Columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with data for the Hubway system in Boston and I'm trying to count up the number of rides that start in the morning hours and the number that start in the evening. I either get an error or I get an output of 0 for both variables, morning and evening. Here's what I have now:

```
# Importing the data:
data = []
trip = open("ExData-trips.csv")
print(trip.readline().split(",")

for row in trip:
    row = row.split(",")
    row = [convert(x) for x in row]
    data.append(row)

# Trying to divide the morning and evening times from the data above:
ride_times = [convert_date(row[3]) for row in data]
#pd.to_datetime(trip['start_date'].dt.hour

morning = 0
evening = 0

for time in trip:
    if time.hour < 12:
        morning += 1
    else:
        evening += 1
print(morning)
print(evening)
```

Output: 0 and 0

I've tried using the commented out line, `#pd.to_datetime(trip['start_date']).dt.hour`, but I get an error:

> TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Sorry if the formatting is off, first time I've asked a question on this forum. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: seems like you're using `pandas` at some point; why don't you read the csv to a pandas DataFrame? You can then select parts of the data where date/time meets certain conditions.

Comment: have you tried loading the file into pandas? `pandas.read_csv("ExData-trips.csv")`